# Trouble with the jquery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have this

```
<button class="create">create</button>
<button class="check">check</button>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#set_state").change(function() {
       var theState = $(this).val();
       $.cookie('set_state', theState, {
           expires: 5,
           path: '/'
       });
  });
  $(".check").click(function() {
      alert("Your Selected Value from Cookie is : " + $.cookie('set_state'));
  });
  $(".delete").click(function() {
       $.cookie('set_state', '', {
        expires: -1
       });
       $("#set_state").val("");
       alert('Cookie is deleted now, try to get cookie..!');
   });
});
```

which I got from another thread. I am very new to this and I can't figure out why my alert reads "Your Selected Value from Cookie is : undefined". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you first need to create the cookie before you set any value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $set_state = $.cookie('set_state');
    ... etc
```

then you can refer to the cookie using the var name instead

```
alert("Your Selected Value from Cookie is : " + $set_state );
```

**Notice** that the value of the cookie will remain `null` within the same session and until the next page refresh.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsGnq/)**

Click *create* and *check* and it will return `null`.
Then refresh the page and *check* will return the value of the cookie.